# Change cell colour on all cells with 1

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm trying to change cell colour on all cells with value = "1"
It is on gridview with databound columns
Looks like this
[image]

The code i have tried is this, but thos changes cells with more numbers then only "1"

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().IndexOf("1") > -1)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this is WPF?

Comment: No it is c# and webform

Comment: the numbers 1 & 0, are they rendered as a label?

Post the frontend markup and the data being rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Equals("1"))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.